# Acceptable page loading time

Tags: time, loading

Base in your experience, what do you reckon is an acceptable page load time? 
I've seen some people saying less than 2 sec and some less than 5 sec. Nowadays technology has evolved and I think we need to take in consideration the type of site we are talking about... Looking forward to get your experiences/answers.

Thanks

Comment: This really sounds like an opinion based question.  Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Chris... I know that probably there is no right or wrong answer. All I'm expecting is knowledge share based in the experience (probably with clients) regarding the acceptable loading time?

Answer (score 2):

Under 3 seconds I suppose is the popular one. But obviously there may be many variables, like if you built a giant site with tons of content, 3 seconds may be hard to achieve.

As fast as possible -- it could further be determined what kind of website and that type of websites audience and stats toward their attention, conversions, bounce rates etc. After seeing that information maybe you can conclude your website must load at x seconds no matter what, or there's a large probability of loss of users, etc. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for that Secret Agent. On this page I'm getting data like most viewed, latest, most searched and some carousel. I'd say that is quite a big amount of data and I'm getting something like 4.5s. I think is quite reasonable. Thanks once again